# How do I print a certain line of python code using the Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, python

If I am writing some python and I only want the terminal to show a certain line, what command do I use?
For example my program is:
print("line one")
print("line two")
print("line three")

And I only want the code in line two to appear in the terminal - print("line two") - 
The command I'd use to run the whole program is python programname.py but how do I print a specific line?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you in interactive python shell? Are you writing code in a text editor? Do you want to print a line from a source file according to some pattern? What does python have to do with this question?

Comment: I'm writing code in the gedit text editor and then running the code in the terminal using the python command. this could probably apply to any language but I'm learning python at the moment

Comment: We would love to help, but we need to know what you are trying to do. Please read you question, imagine you are not you, imagine you are me, I do not know what you know, I do not know what you are trying to do. Now tell be what you are trying to do. Where are you when you want to show one line. This one line, what is it one line of (the python program, output from python program, input, something else). Please improve question, don't add comment.

Comment: It's literally a really simply program, it's just a load of lines allowing me to print something like print("a line") and I want to just see line 5 for example when running the program in the terminal, I'm pretty new to programming so I'm not sure how to explain it much clearer, I'm sorry

Comment: Just guessing here... to just print 9'th line from a file, say `sed -n '9{p;q}' yourfile.py`. But unless this has some profound scripting use, you could just as easily find the wanted line in a text editor. If you want to evaluate just one line in python, this is not the best idea. Also, you can experiment in interactive python shell much better -- print out arbitrary variables, check function definitions, use command history.

Comment: I'll try that out thanks :) I've put a more detailed description in my question now, hopefully it's a little clearer

Comment: If you add as first line `#!/usr/bin/python` and then do `chmod +x myprogram.py`, then you can remove the `.py` extension, and run the program like this `…/myprogram`, there … is path to `myprogram`. This way you do not need to know that it is written in python to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to view the `n`th line of a file, you could simply do:

```
sed -n '42p' yourfile.py
```

Replace `42` with whatever line number you want to see.

After your edit: If you also want to *execute* this code, simply pipe it to `python`:

```
sed -n '42p' yourfile.py | python
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate `awk` solution:

```
awk "NR==2" programname.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with bash/shell, you can write a python script to do that too!

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# usage: ./script file line_no
import sys
data = ''
with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')
try:
    print data[sys[2] +1]
except IndexError:
    print "Line doesn't exist"
```

NOTE: This is just a quick and dirty example. You can improve it to your liking.

Comment: Ahh. Didn't notice this is an old question. My bad :')

Answer (score -2):

Based on @DoorKnob answer, and in case of someone finding this in a search and **wanting to find nth line of output**. Then do this.

```
run-program | sed -n '2p'
```

This will print the 42nd output line of `run-program`

e.g.

```
python yourfile.py | sed -n `2p`
```

Comment: The question clearly states "I only want the **code** in line two to appear in the terminal".

Comment: Sorry I did not read it properly, I have updated the answer in accordance to your comment.

Comment: They're both incorrect because they're both filtering program output. You're probably better of deleting the answer since there is another one already accepted.